# Increment version number in versioninfo in tfsbuild CI

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have a C# web solution, and I am in the process of setting it up in [TFSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558974%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 2010. As I am new to this, I require assistance as to how I can achieve certain tasks.

My issue is with version numbers. At present I use one VersionInfo file to hold the version number. When I run my build I would like to take this version number, increment it and use it as the main version number for the build. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the [Community TFS Build extensions pack](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), and use the AssemblyInfo task. However, if you need to something a little different or need to customize it more. You will need to create a custom activity. Some good documentation is in blog post *[Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 1: Introduction](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx)*.

I use a build number format of `BuildDefinitionName_Major.Minor.(YY)(DayOfYear).(rr)` and then take off everything after the underscore and use the number left to parse out to an assembly version and assembly file version.

It really is amazing and stupifying to think that Microsoft hasn't baked in a better mechanism yet. As how to handle this is one of the most asked questions with team build and who on Earth would run a build without an automated mechanism to handle the versioning?